# Google Maps API v3 with Wordpress? Different maps on different posts, with common styles

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I've familiarized myself with the Google Maps PI v3 enough that I can make the kind of maps I want, with the custom markers and info windows that I need. What I can't seem to find info on is integrating this into something like a Wordpress blog. I know there are plugins, but none of them seem to be what I'm looking for.

Here's what I'd like to do: In my header file, included the basic code for Google maps, including styles. In whatever blog post I use a map, included specific code on geolocation, zoom level, marker, and info window.

Is this possible? How would I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: my last example was supposed to be a general idea... Here's a working implementation.

html

```
map 1
<div class="gmap">{"center":{"lat":46.87916,"lon":-3.32910,"zoom":6},"type":"terrain","markers":[{"lat":46.87916,"lon": -3.32910,"info":"some info here"}]}</div>
map 2
<div class="gmap">{"center":{"lat":46.87916,"lon":-3.32910,"zoom":6},"type":"terrain","markers":[{"lat":46.87916,"lon": -3.32910,"info":"some info here"}]}</div>
```

jquery to create the maps

```
$(".gmap").each(function() {
    var data = $.parseJSON($(this).html());
    $(this).html("");
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: data.center.zoom,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(data.center.lat, data.center.lon),
        mapTypeId: data.type
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(this, myOptions);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.markers.length; i++) {
        var marker = data.markers[i];
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lon),
            title: marker.info,
            map: map
        });
    }
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/djs5x/1/
json generator: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/153/

Comment: Thanks, but nothing's happening when I try this. The map just doesn't generate. Not sure what I might be doing wrong, I'm not as familiar with Jquery.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! It works now. Your first answer probably would have been good enough for someone who actually knew what they were doing, but thanks for clarifying. Thanks for the prompt response as well.